# Branch in GitLab is not in list of branches in Terminal

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

I have a repository in GitLab that has several (more than three) branches. The ones relevant to this question are release/2020mar, feature/(the task name), and release/2021mar. Apparently, I created the feature branch (the branch my changes are in) off of release/2020mar. I don't know whether release/2021mar was available at the time (can't remember). In any event, I pushed my branch to GitLab and did a merge request to release/2021mar. My tech lead says I'm 5 commits behind and I need to update my feature branch to be in sync with release/2021mar.

So here's the thing: in my Terminal/Git Bash, when I type the command 'git branch', it only lists two branches: the feature branch and release/2020mar. It does not list release/2021mar (or any of the other branches). I tried doing 'git checkout release/2021mar', but I got a message saying "error:pathspec 'release/2021mar' did not match any files known to git".

I'm not sure what is going on, and I can't seem to find the right search terms or phrase to find an answer on the Internet. Can anyone here tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+list+branches

Answer (score 0):

Yes "git fetch origin" pushes the missing branches into the origin.
For me the I could not "checkout" into the branch. It was still giving me same ERROR output.
Had to RE-START the terminal to effect the changes.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I had to do 'git fetch origin.'